# Subclass method have weaker access specifier. But i can override. How did this happen?

Tags: java

Why output of this code is class A? Because there is rule subclass overridden method can not have a weaker access specifier. For this rule i think output is must be class B. Please explain why output is class A?

```
public class B {
    
    public void foo(){
        System.out.println("class B");
    }
    
}

public class A extends B{
    
    protected void foo(){
        System.out.println("class A");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new A();
        b.foo();
        //output class A
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what it outputs to you, but in my IDE it throws error, because I am trying to assign weaker access privilege.

Comment: That's strange. What compiler do you use? Mine reports an error, `Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from B`. May be your `foo()` methods are different actually and just look the same, e.g. their names are written in different encodings? See: `fоо()` and `foo()` are different words though look equal (copy them from here into a text editor and look at the char codes). Add `@Override` before the overridden method to make sure it's really overridden.

Comment: My ide is Netbeans. When i clean and build project reports error.